# Nested Loop Issue, prints out wrong number

Tags: java, for-loop

Trying to print out these sequences of numbers using nested for loops for a programming worksheet but i'm having difficulty, can someone help please?

> 133355555

```
int i, j;
for (i = 1; i < 6; i+=2) {
    for (j = 1; j < i+3; j+=2) {
            System.out.print(i);
    } 
}
```

// the above code prints out an extra '1' at the start, how do I modify it so that it prints 133355555 instead.

cheers !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keeping your inner for-loop simpler:

`for(j=1;j<=i;j++)`

Comment: Cheers for the help mate, been trying to figure this out for ages !!

Answer (score 1):

It's because the first execution of the inner loop loops twice for `j = 1` and `j = 3`. Both 1 and 3 are lower than `i + 3`, which equals 4 for the first iteration.

Anyway, is this a particular case of a more generic requirement? If not, you can simply write `System.out.print("133355555");`